# Implemention Zigbee Home Automation

Tags: automation, zigbee, home-automation

Are there any open source libraries to implement Home Automation Profile for zigbee?
The end device does not necessarily belong to a particular developer.

Comment: What hardware platform and ZigBee stack are you using?  In pretty much every case, you're going to use the stack provided by the hardware manufacturer, and that stack should include an HA implementation.

Comment: There aren't (see @carneseca answer for details). Anyway you can grab a free copy of the [ZigBee Home Automation Standard](http://www.zigbee.org/zigbee-for-developers/applicationstandards/zigbeehomeautomation/) from their website.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any, although not for a lack of trying. The reason they don't exist is that the ZigBee Alliance is very protective of their trademarks, and won't let you use "ZigBee" without becoming a paying member of the alliance.

This effectively killed the open source ZigBee project a few years ago.

The HA profile itself requires certification through the ZigBee Alliance, so you'll find this same issue whether it's a stack or profile.

Comment: Say, if we purchase NXP chip as well as their HA device, will we be able to access the functions relevant to communication from the SDK that they provide along with the device?

Comment: You have the right idea. NXP's ZigBee stack provides the API and callbacks (via .h files) that you need to communicate using ZigBee. You don't need to implement the protocol yourself (or go looking for an open source stack to use). They also provide an implementation of the HA profile, the completeness of which depends on what clusters you need. They have support for some common clusters. However, if you require certain clusters that NXP doesn't support, you would have to implement those yourself.